# Skype for business large file recording

Tags: skype-for-business

I used Skype for Business during a training session to record audio and screen sharing to document a process for about a 3-hour session. After the training was over and stopped recording, it took 3 hours to create the mp4 file (of size 1.3GB). Even after 14 hours the status is Creating 100% and it is not changing to completed. Because of this I am not able to either open the created mp4 file not able to record further sessions.

My guess is due to the file size, but if anyone can suggest how to retrieve the bigger mp4 file you are welcome.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In my experience your going to be out of luck, the video doesn't appear to have been created properly. Restarting the system should make it possible to make new videos though

Comment: SOLVED - One of my colleague suggested deleting the item from the recording manager, double clicking any of the *frd** file and opening it with skype for business recording manager. The file creation took place again and completed without hassles this time.

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer and accept it. This will mark the question as solved. Please read: [*Can I answer my own question?*](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: The Microsoft Office components are using Hardware acceleration. We have seen that creating the record somethimes didn´t finish as the Graphic card driver is not up to date and is causing issues in the creation process. So we went to the vendor website and updated the drivers from there (please do not use any kind of driver update tool, most are fake software) and that solved our issue.